# What determines which heat energy meter is mine in a duplex?

Tags: heating, meter, energy

I am specifically referring to meters for heat/AC energy.

Our duplex has two meters, but when I went to submit our reading and create our account it said that the one with the lower reading was not the one attached to our bill.

I assume that the lower reading would be ours because

1. It is just me and my husband in our suite, the neighbors are a couple with a toddler.
2. The neighbors have an extra room to heat.
3. We don't let our heat 'run in the background'. To save money, we only turn it on when we feel physically too cold and we promptly turn it off when it reaches the set temperature.
4. Finally, we haven't ran our heat in almost a month, I can literally hear theirs click in each morning. Is there any chance they are being billed for our meter and we are getting theirs? They have been here for a few years, we have only been here for two months.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the meters?

Comment: Are you referring to the electric meters?

Comment: The value on the face of the meter will be cumulative from when it was first installed. To know the usage, you need to take a reading, wait some set amount of time (24 hours, say), take another reading, then subtract. This will give you the amount of energy used over that time period.

Comment: Turning your heat on and off is not necessarily more energy efficient than leaving it set to a constant temp. Mass holds heat, Reheating the mass takes a lot of energy. More people per household does not necessarily mean more energy usage. Broad generalizations but doing some research on how to make the most energy efficient decisions will inform your choices and effect your energy use/bill

Comment: Did you ask them how you can tell which one IS  attached to your bill ? Presumably if they know which one is not then they know which one is. ?? Heat can be gas or electric, you did not specify.

Comment: Are the meters not marked as to which unit they go to?!

Answer (score 2):

Turn all of your heat / AC devices off then go out and verify one is moving and one that is not. Many utilities have the tag number from the meter or seal on the bill. With smart meters ID tags are much more common.